# How to model staging data in a datawarehouse

Tags: database, modeling, data-warehouse

We have around 200 files coming in from the client to our data warehouse on a regular basis.  I'm trying to design the warehouse specifically the staging area, I'm hesitant to stage the data in the database:-

1. It creates lot of redundant data, since we will be anyway storing the data in dimensional model and will be storing the files in file system
2. In staging we are not adding value to data other than basic count and precision checks etc

I'm thinking to instead create external table for each file type and grab data straight from the file and load to dimension after transformation.  However struggling with these issues:

- What if the file layout changes, although we are planning to store all the files, the external table will be able to read only one layout at a time and the old files will become unusable.  We do need to read historical data from time to time and we are planning to aggregate the data in single file for each file type.
- How do we do basic validations like counts, datatype, precision check etc from the external table and more importantly how do we figure out how many and which records have errored out - ideally want to store error records in a different structure

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Data duplication is a necessary evil in data warehousing. Use your staging tables, but don't save all the history data in them. Truncate the table, and load each new file when batch runs. That way you have easy access to the "most recently loaded" batch of records, for debugging any issues that arise, as well as doing your data quality work.

The file layout should not change without advance warning to the data warehouse team. If it is, you have a business communication problem, not a data warehouse problem.